# Define a minimum number character in UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsuinteger

I wish verify a number letter in UITextfield, and also if my textfield is empty. But, I have a problem between NSUInteger and int. Thanks for your answers.

```
- (void)saveProfile {

    NSUInteger *minID = [_userID.text length];

    if ([_userID.text isEqualToString:@""] == NO || minID >= 4) {
         // Succes
    } else { // Error }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
NSUInteger *minID = [_userID.text length];
```

to

```
NSUInteger minID = [_userID.text length];
```

The length property is defined like:

```
@property(readonly) NSUInteger length
```

So the `length` getter method will return a `NSUInteger` not `NSUInteger *`

Refer : [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/length) for more details